# init system vs configuration management

Tags: puppet, configuration-management, upstart, ansible, systemd

Best practice:

What tasks would you give to an init system  like systemd vs a configuration management system like ansible? What I like about starting up services with a CM is portability across different Linuxes but I don't think a CM is as robust as an init system.

Comment: I fail to see how one replaces the other. When you say "start  a service" using `puppet` on a `systemd` system, `puppet` will just run `systemctl start <service>`.

Comment: yes but you can have a CM install a service and run it too *and* manage services which you could w/o involving a CM. if you have an init system do those all you might be doing through a CM is passing the init system some configuration parameters/file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt many people use their CM agent as their primary system to manage services.

Mostly configuration management is used to configure the your OS init system, and it uses the init system features to start/stop things.